# Getting most recent entry at a given date

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection `vehiclelocation` in MongoDB which is like this :

```
{
    _id: ...,
    Vehicle: ...,
    Location: ....,
    Date: ....
}
```

It contains an history of vehicle locations.

I have two criteria for my query : a location,  and a date.
I need to get the list of vehicles of which the last known location at a given date is the one from my criteria.
I was able to do that in SQL, but I'm trying to migrate to Mongo, and can't figure out how to write that.

A more simple alternative is to get the last known location of the vehicles at a given date.
It's easy to do that for one specific vehicle,  but I don't how to do that for all the vehicles in one query.

Is there any way to do it with MongoDB ?

**EDIT:**

I tried this:

```
db.runCommand( {aggregate:"vehiclelocationhistory", pipeline: [
   {$match: {DateTime:{$lte:ISODate("2013-08-02T10:50:00Z")}}}, 
   {$sort:{DateTime:-1}}, 
   {$group:{_id:"$VehicleId", LocationId: {$first: "$LocationId"} } }], allowDiskUse:true})
```

But I had to add "allowDiskUse" which means it is consuming a lot of memory.

Comment: Why did I get -1 ?
I already spend some time to find an answer without any success.

Comment: Your pipeline gets you the answer to your second query, but you have too many results to group because the date filter extends unbounded into the past. Try restricting to just one date using a `$gte` and a `$lte`. Be sure also to index on `DateTime` to make the first match/sort fast.